# Get ListView from widget layout

Tags: android, listview, widget, remoteview

I want to add items from a service in a ListView which is displayed in a widget. But how can I get my ListView in the Service? My widget layout looks like this:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>
```

And with this Code I can get the RemoteViews from my widget:

```
AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(ctx);
RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
```

But now how can I get my ListView from the RemoteViews?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/laaptu/appwidget-listview/tree/appwidget-listview1) is an example which seems to do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a RemoteViewFactory class which is the adaptor for your ListView;

```
rv.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.listView1,
                            serviceIntent);
```

Go through [this](http://laaptu.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/android-app-widget-with-listview/) link. I guess this is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried with that but the widget does not update. Here I have posted my problem. Would be nice if you acn have a look on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704139/listview-in-widget-does-not-update

Comment: Can you tell me how I can set an OnItemClickListener for this ListView?