# ListView in widget does not update

Tags: android, android-listview, android-widget

I want to update a ListView in a widget from a service. For this I have this code in my service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, ListProvider.class);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(widgetId, R.id.listViewWidget, intent);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
```

I'm sure that the service is running and the code is executed but in the widget on the homescreen nothing happens. My ListProvider looks like this:

```
public class ListProvider implements RemoteViewsFactory
{
    public ListProvider(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        Log.d("ME",  "new ListProvider");

        this.context = context;
        appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

        populateListItem();
    }

    private void populateListItem() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
            listItem.heading = "Heading" + i;
            listItem.content = i + " This is the content";
            listItemList.add(listItem);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return listItemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) 
    {
        final RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_row);
        ListItem listItem = listItemList.get(position);

        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.heading, listItem.heading);
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.content, listItem.content);

        return remoteView;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() 
    {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() 
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Some other override methods

    public class ListItem 
    {
        public String heading,content;
    }
}
```

And this is my AppWidgetProvider:

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider
{
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) 
    {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }
}
```

But the ListProvider is never called I think. The Log message is not displayed and on the homescreen nothing happens. Any ideas why?

Comment: How do you send an Intent from service to your widget?

Comment: I thought that it is enought if I change the ListView over the `RemoteView` and than call the widget update function with `updateAppWidget`. Is that not enought? I do not work so often with widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a service to update the remote adapter:

```
public class UpdateWidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {
    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
        return new ListProvider(this.getApplicationContext(), intent);
    }
}
```

And use the service class instead of the RemoteViewFactory directly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; ++i) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, UpdateWidgetService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
    serviceIntent.setData(Uri.parse(serviceIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.stackWidgetView, serviceIntent);
    remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.stackWidgetView, R.id.no_data_imageview);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);
}
```

*Never tested it in a listView.*

Comment: Okay it updates now but it allways displays the `no_data_imageview` and no items in the `ListView`.

Comment: post your AppWidgetProvider class

Comment: My AppWidgetProvider only calls `super.onUpdate()` because I thought I gets the changed `RemoteView` over the IDs. I edit my question above.

Comment: NO it cannot have only super.onUpdate  ...you need to add the code in my answer {for (int i=0....} in the onUpdate followed by super.onUpdate

Comment: http://laaptu.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/android-app-widget-with-listview/         follow this tutorial first and then change the onUpdate method and the UpdateWidgetService as mentioned in my answer

Comment: Hi @AabidMulani can you help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39266206/items-on-listview-in-widget-doesnt-display-android/39266250#39266250 my code is like your code above but the result doesn't display on my listview. Thanks